# Regenerating cookie_secret

Tags: turbogears2

In the turbogears `development.ini` file, there's a value something like this:

> cookie_secret = aabbccdd-eeff-0011-2233-445566778899

consisting of hexadecimal digits and dashes.
The same value is placed in `beaker.session.secret` and `beaker.session.validate_key`.

http://turbogears.org/2.0/docs/main/Config.html has a section on this value:

> The beaker.session.secret key of the base_config object contains the secret used to store user sessions. Pylons automatically generates a random secret for you when you create a project. If an attacker gets his hands on this key, he will be able to forge a valid session an use your application at though he was logged in. In the event of a security breach, you can change this key to invalidate all user sessions.

What's the best way to generate a new key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be anything you want. Better if hard to catch or bruteforce. Same rules of password apply. It is currently generated with uuid.uuid4() if I remember correctly